# Interstitial ad when view controller loads

Tags: ios, swift, admob, uistoryboardsegue, interstitial

I am trying to show an interstitial ad after a segue when the viewAppears, but the ad does not show and I do not know where I am going wrong.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        intersitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-***************")
        let request = GADRequest()
        intersitial.load(request)
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if intersitial.isReady {
            intersitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Implement delegate methods to check the error. I faced the same the day I was trying to load ad was not showing up. with error no ad to show   but next day it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the development phone or simulator doesnt show the ads (maybe just one time). But when you upload to App store , if you download another device you can see the Ads properly. Just Be sure complete all codes and delegates.

Comment: the problem is if intersitial.isReady {
        intersitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }     doesn't get called in viewDidLoad